# componentDidMount and XMLHttpRequest loaded data twice with not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm using simple express static server to manage static files.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Here is a ***webpack.config.js*** file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()    
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015','react']
      }
    }]
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map'
}
```

And here is my Question React component ***question.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const stackAddress = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?site=stackoverflow';

class Question extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.loadDataFromStack = this.loadDataFromStack.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      itemList: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Load data from Stack');
    this.loadDataFromStack()
  }

  loadDataFromStack(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET',stackAddress, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = () => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
    };
    request.send()
  }
  render(){
    return <div>
      <h1>Questions</h1>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
  }
}

export default Question
```

When i am running the server i get the [next error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y29Cz.png) and also as i noticed i got request twice as you can see on a screen.

but if i use *jQuery.get* or *jQuery.ajax* methods than it works well

Could someone suggest where is a problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that this may be the issue but normally, when doing a XMLHttpRequest you should set up your handler BEFORE you call open. So I will try like this:

```js
loadDataFromStack(){
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
       console.log(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
    }
  };
  request.open('GET',stackAddress, true);
  request.send()
}
```

Note `request.onreadystatechange = ()` should be called before `request.open('GET',stackAddress, true);`

Comment: oh, of course! it's not controlling the state, I will modify the answer so you can see what happens

Comment: I added if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) to only call the log when the data is received